# How can I use a doctrine connection to import a SQL file?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have an app that needs to import a .sql file. I can import the file from the command line with `mysql -u my_user -pMyPassword db_name < import.sql`, but I'd like to move this into my app. I have some things that need to be done before the import and others after. Right now I have to break it into 3 steps. The closest to a solution I've found was to get the connection (`Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`) and use `exec()` but it throws syntax errors even though my source file is correct. I'm guessing it's trying to escape things and double escaping the SQL. The file was generated with `mysqldump`.

Comment: Have you found any solution so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [the DBAL "import" command](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Tools/Console/Command/ImportCommand.php) and get the sql executed. This is anyway less performant than using the mysql command directly, since it [loads the entire file into memory](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Tools/Console/Command/ImportCommand.php#L80).

Otherwise, I'd suggest you to use your own [Symfony Console Command](https://github.com/symfony/Console).

Comment: Yeah, deprecated and gone. Maybe you can suggest an edit to this answer?

Answer (score 7):

With Symfony using Doctrine, you can do it with:

```
php app/dev_console doctrine:database:import import.sql
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/3241, this has been removed from Doctrine

Answer (score 2):

in my case it was :

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:import my_sql_file.sql
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/3241, this has been removed from Doctrine

Comment: @Nico Haase what's the alternative then?

Comment: That's something you should ask the maintainers of Doctrine. According to the pull request, there is no replacement :(

Comment: According to what i just did, it works again ‍♂️ Thx 

Answer (score 0):

Status September 2021:

I rather trust the code in Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\ImportDoctrineCommand which calls a deprecation-warning in the execute function. It is not good programming practice to ignore deprecation warnings. Calling dual:run-sql would not be efficient enough because of the overhead.
Alternatively, you can also call e.g. mysql on the operating system level. This causes problems in multi-user environments, for example because the database password has to be specified on the command line. In addition, the server must also activate this function; exec() is switched off for security reasons in many environments, especially with low-cost providers. Furthermore, this function would not be database abstract. This abstraction is one of the most outstanding features of Doctrine.

Therefore, I recommend reading in the SQL data yourself and executing it line by line (see entityManager->createNativeSQL() function). You then have better possibilities to react to possible errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).